# UBUNTU 22.10 Internal microphone partially working on new Asus Laptop

Tags: laptop, asus, microphone

I had to pick up a new ASUS Expertbook B1500 laptop (11th gen). Bought it yesterday, installed Ubuntu 22.10 (minimal install) and added all the apps the family member wanted.

Everything seems to work except the internal microphone.
pulseaudio controller reports it as "C-Media(R)Audio"
System profiler and benchmark report it as being from ASUSTek, but also says the vendor is SEAGATE.

Here is where it gets interesting.
It may be a stereo microphone as there are 2 holes shown and the manual seems to indicate it.

'pulseaudio volume control' gets absolutely nothing from it, no matter what profile I choose.
I even try unlocking the left and right channels on the mic and set one to zero, but no joy.

Gnome settings->audio does show it to be there but nothing comes out.
skype won't  pick anything up either, although the camera works.
An external webcam works fine though.

cheese crashes when I try to record video.
webcamoid does do video but no audio, even if I choose ALSA.

I've cranked alsamixer to the max on everything I can find.

But here is the rub... audacity will work if I choose the correct 'recording device'.
Now the host is ALSA, so I'm guessing it is bypassing pulseaudio.
'pulseaudio volume control' doesn't recognise audacity as recording anything.
Under profiles, there is a 'C-Media(R) Audio' section (which I have been testing) and a 'Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller' section (but it is permanently 'Off').

I'm just not sure if it is a driver issue or something or pulseaudio misreading something.
I am getting quite a lot of errors when I type 'pulseaudio' into the terminal.

```
W: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Stale PID file, overwriting.
E: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Failed to find a working profile.
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
E: [pulseaudio] socket-server.c: bind(): Address already in use
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-native-protocol-unix" (argument: ""): initialization failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: D-Bus name org.pulseaudio.Server already taken.
E: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Failed to find a working profile.
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
E: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Failed to find a working profile.
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
E: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Failed to find a working profile.
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
E: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Failed to find a working profile.
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
E: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Failed to find a working profile.
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
W: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: Tried to configure /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0 (alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic) more often than 5 times in 10s
W: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: Tried to configure /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0 (alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic) more often than 5 times in 10s
```

I'm at my wits end, no sure if 23.04 in less than a week is going to fix it or not.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title. Accepting your answer is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to this was the upgrade to v23.04.
It allowed the "Tigerlake" profile to be enabled in the "pulseaudio volume controller" (pulsevc)

I'm still getting a lot of annoying errors showing up at boot time, but the sound works and I can pass it on to the owner.

So a functional fix is:

1. forget the whole volume L/R & alsamixer solutions
2. install 23.04
3. install pulseaudio volume control
4. enable the Tigerlake profile & also make sure you have 'analog stereo duplex'
5. in gnome->settings->sound set the microphone to the last Tigerlake option (channel 7, in my case).

You should instantly see the indicator start moving when you make sound.

---

Word of warning though.... if you use any recording tools and select something other than the tigerlake option for microphone, the tigerlake profile will turn off in "pulsevc".

but it is easy to go to the program and turn the profile back on and then set it up in gnome->settings->sound